# Remove repeating column values in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data set that has dates and subtotal of other columns.
[image]

I want to remove the same recurring dates per subtotal

[image]

Comment: Please see this link for [how to ask good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the index of the current DataFrame using its existing columns with the help of [DataFrame.set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html).

```py
df.set_index(['w/c Mon', 'Portfolio'])
```